# How does Ian Stewart's Complex Analysis Textbook compare to the more commonly used text?

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am trying to find a good complex analysis text for self study and I was wondering what people think of Ian Stewart's complex analysis text. I was trying to find some reviews on this forum but most people recommend other books and it seems like most people have not actually tried Stewart's text. Since I haven't really studied complex analysis, I can't tell exactly how good the text does at covering each topic. Has anyone tried self learning with this text?

Answer (score 2):

> Ian Stewart's book *[Complex Analysis](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/complex-analysis/6B37DF4AB124D4FB3A16869448D5E31D)* is both, a gentle and solid introductory text into complex analysis.
>
> There are two recurrent themes the author uses to motivate and guide the reader. On the one hand the historical development of complex numbers and complex analysis is nicely addressed, on the other hand he often uses familiar properties, facts and theorems from real analysis to show analogies and to also point out differences in complex analysis.
>
> The last three chapters
>
> - Infinitesimals in Real and Complex Analysis
> - Homology Version of Cauchy's Theorem
> - The Road Goes Ever On ...
>
> are a supplement to previous chapters and a view to other topics somewhat beyond the canon of an introductory text.

A reason that this book is not that often discussed might be that Ian Stewart is more widely known for his popular mathematical books. In fact the first book I've had the pleasure to read from him was *[The Problems of Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0192192019)* nearly $30$ years ago.

Comment: I like his Introductory remark “Hitchhikers Guide to the Plane.Don’t forget your towel Towels can be transformed into anything with the correct Homeomorphism 